# How to get equal padding in between columns for my tkinter GUI pathfinder?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently creating a GUI with tkinter in python for a Pathfinder app. My code up until now has a grid of 5 by 5 with an S (starting point) and G (goal/ end point) and all cells in between are random numbers. I also have a reset button that re-generates the numbers randomly, creating a different field every time. The problem now is that I do not get the output I want. I want the cells of the grid to be next to each other, seperated only by lines (_). I already tried to set the padding to 0, but that did not help. The output now gives correct padding between the first and second column, but not between the second and third column. It seems as if the third column has a way larger width. Does anyone know how i can get the correct output of a grid that has equal width and height columns, not being seperated?

Here is the code I used:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class PathFinder:
    def init(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("PathFinder game")
        self.grid_design()self.reset_button()

    def grid_design(self):
        self.labels = [[tk.Label(self.parent, text = str(random.randint(1, 10)), width=6, height=3, relief='solid') for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
        self.labels[4][0].config( text = "S")           
        self.labels[0][4].config( text = "G")           

        for row in range(5):
            for column in range(5):
                self.labels[row][column].grid(row=row, column=column, padx=0, pady=0)

    def reset_button(self):
        self.reset_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='Create new random field', command=self.reset_grid)
        self.reset_button.grid(row=5, column=2, pady=10)
    
    def reset_grid(self):
        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(5):
                if not (row == 4 and col == 0) and not (row == 0 and col == 4):
                    new_value = str(random.randint(1, 10))
                    self.labels[row][col].config(text=new_value)


root = tk.Tk()
app = PathFinder(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you put a long button at column 2.  Put it in column 0 with `columnspan=5` instead:

Note also that `def init(self, parent)` should be `def __init__(self, parent)` instead.

```py
class PathFinder:
    def __init__(self, parent):   # should be __init__ instead
        ...

    ...
 
    def reset_button(self):
        self.reset_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='Create new random field', command=self.reset_grid)
        self.reset_button.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=10)

    ...
```

Result:

[image]